How to handle connection pooling in multitenant app (multiple app server and tenant per db)?
We are trying to build a multi-tenant app(using spring boot) with single db per tenant. We currently have less than 100 tenants but we expect around 1000 in 2-3 years.
We have multiple app server which connects to multiple SQL databases that creates connection through AWS secret manager but the problem is the connection is resource heavy and we are facing some time limit to create connection.
One solution we have thought of is to have some in-memory db like Redis which store information of users/tenants requests that have been forwarded to a app-server and that server has connection to a database so any new requests from that tenant is redirected towards the same app-server and so on and any new tenant requests is redirected to new app-server.
Is this a viable solution and are there any tested solution. Can you share some resources to look into?

I think you will receive more and better answers by posting your question on software engineering instead of on SO. SO is more focussed on solving actual (code) problems and less on design/engineering questions. Good question though!
